# php curl login, get parameter in url

Tags: php, curl

I have this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.web.com/index.php?q=login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "nick=abc&pass=abc");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);


print_r($server_output);
```

On this address www.web.com/index.php?q=login is a login form. I am trying to log there but without any success.(`$server_output` still contains only login form - it should contains user panel - after successfull login)

Comment: You'll probably need to accept cookies. See the questions in the "related" column to the right

Comment: I added this lines to the code: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); but without any result ..

Comment: What do you need the login for? Is there no http API for logging in?

Comment: I want to show my messages from this website(I can access them only after login), but I am doing it just for a test

Comment: Sometimes, annoyingly, aren't any convenient shotcuts for testing. What's more, when you come to do this properly you'll have rewriting to do. I guess you've written some kind of log in form in php? The first step (though by no means the last) would be to do this with proper auth: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php, instead of postfields, and then with curl (many links here- e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792419/php-curl-accessing-url-with-http-authentication-need-help)

Comment: I should add- am I right to presume you've written this other website too?

Comment: I made first test with my second website, it works there perfectly, but now I am trying to login into other website(which I didn't make) and it isn't working there..even I got session id in cookie.txt but it's stil not working

Comment: Oh ok- well this other website probably won't use postfields like you do to log in? How have you deduced what kind of auth this other website uses? What's the actual website url?

Comment: Actually it use this postfields, but nevermind. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to conduct other operations like accepting cookies, here is some code which you can use to initialize your curl.

```
$this->_ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```