# Accessing directory listing on another domain using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I searched a lot but couldn't find a code that worked.
Essentially, I want to read the files in a folder (abc.com/folder) which has directory listing enabled using a code hosted on xyz.com. The folder is password protected (htaccess) and asks for username and password before the directory listing can be accessed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: use curl or http url loginmechanismus and read the output from the server parse it in the way you like

Comment: Just search and you can find things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792419/php-curl-accessing-url-with-http-authentication-need-help