# How can I fix the redirect issues with git-backend-http on Windows 10 with XAMPP

Tags: git, xampp, remote-repository

Currently, I'm using XAMPP as my web server.

Now, I want to makes a git repository in my web server.

As a result, I want to run this command line perfectly:

```
$ git-config remote.upload.url http://paultester@<servername>/new-repo.git/
$ git push upload master
```

I followed this guideline:
http://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/post/37/Installing+Git+http-backend+on+Windows+with+XAMPP

But I got this error

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://paultester@<servername>/new-repo.git/': Maximum (20) redirects followed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `git-config remote.upload.url http://…` should be written as `git remote add upload http://…` or `git remote set-url upload http://…` if the remote exists.

Comment: In my case, I guess the command run OK because `.git/config` file has `[remote "upload"] url = http://paultester@<servername>/new-repo.git/`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can set on the server side [`curl-setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792441/6309)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

An alternative to XAMPP server would be one binary (no configuration) with **[Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)**: nothing to install but the binary, and you can do HTTP pushes.

Comment: Gitea is awesome! Many thanks for your recommend. On the other hand, I cannot configure `curl-setopt` on the server side. I made some research but I found nothing.

Comment: @Linherest Did you test Gitea? You might not need to configure curl if you do use it.